# When I try to print, the Print dialog hangs

Tags: windows-7, printer, homegroup

Context:

- 7 printers are 'installed'

Local Printers:

- Canon Inkjet PIXMA iP4000 via USB
- Canon MP460 Printer via USB
- CutePDF Writer (not actually a physical printer)
- Microsoft XPS Document Writer (again, a virtual printer. Also tends to mangle documents)
- Send To OneNote 2007 (virtual printer; spouts garbage with IE)

HomeGroup Printers:

- Canon Inkjet PIXMA iP4000
- Canon MP460

After I press CTRL+P in any application, things come to a halt complete with the Windows "Not Responding" text appearing in the window's titlebar. After a long time, the common Print dialog appears and things return to normal.

How can I get straight to the Print dialog without waiting a long time?

Bonus Details:

- The HomeGroup printers randomly appear to be online/offline even if the computer they are hooked up to is online.
- I rarely hook up the USB cables because it is a hassle to disconnect them from another computer and string them accross the room to my computer setup, which only has 2 easily accessible USB ports located on a Dell monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to stop using printers shared via HomeGroup and to buy a printer that can be shared independently.